# Unable to get the web interface of IBM websphere MQ in Azure Kubernetes

Tags: ibm-mq, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

We are trying to spin up a Stateful MQ manager with default storage Class as persistent storage mounted for data in an Azure Kubernetes cluster. Here is the [link](https://github.com/IBM/charts/tree/master/stable/ibm-mqadvanced-server-dev) which we followed. We exposed the service type as LoadBalancer as shown in below command.

```
helm install stable/ibm-mqadvanced-server-dev --version 3.0.1 --set service.type=LoadBalancer,security.initVolumeAsRoot=true,license=accept
```

Now, we can able to deploy the MQ pod in AKS and it shows the pod status as running. but unable to get the web interface of MQ. Here we are taking service type as LoadBalancer and added security groups for NodePorts created by  LoadBalancer. still, we are failed to access the service. we have checked pod logs and it shows the logs as `Started web server` at the end.

Could anybody suggest what might be the reason for not getting the web interface of IBM WebSphere MQ and what are the possible ways to overcome this issue?

Comment: Can you show the service configuration which exposes your MQ?

Comment: Hello @CharlesXu. Here is the link(https://github.com/IBM/charts/blob/master/stable/ibm-mqadvanced-server-dev/templates/service.yaml) for service configuration and In the install command, we are giving service type as LoadBalancer as mentioned in the Question.

Comment: Can you show the pods and services state?

Comment: pod state showing as running and service has created. here we are taking service type as LoadBalancer?

Comment: That's no problem. You can expose the application in the pods through the service with type load balancer.

Comment: Hi Charles Xu. yeah, I exposed the MQ application in the pods through the service with the type load balancer. still, I am unable to get web UI of My MQ application. I have checked the pod logs as well, it has shown as web server started. so, What might be the issue?

Comment: Maybe the problem is the ports that you expose for the pods and services.

Comment: yeah, I am trying to access the application using LoadBalancer IP and nodePort which has generated.

Comment: Do not use the nodePort to access, just use the port that you expose in the service.

Comment: Thanks, Charles Xu. it's working. now I am able to get the web UI of MQ application.but unable to login. I am using the credentials username as `admin` and password as `passw0rd`. so, Is there any commands to retrieve the default username and password for MQ.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194365/discussion-between-gayathrib-and-charles-xu).